# Loops to normalise data

Tags: r, normalization

Here's a small dataset

```
RWC<-as.data.frame(matrix(1:9,ncol=3))
RWC
V1 V2 V3
 1  4  7  
 2  5  8  
 3  6  9
```

I'm trying to normalise by suming the rows separately and have the original number divide by the sum.
This should lead to this (I do not need the rounding, this is just for convenience).

```
V1    V2    V3
0.08  0.33  0.58  
0.13  0.33  0.53  
0.16  0.33  0.50
```

I've so far written

```
for(i in 3:nrow(RWC)){
  normalise <- sum(row[3:ncol])
  RWC <- ()
}
```

I'm stuck on trying to divide and give the value to the specific row and column, how would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fast way to get the sum in each row is `rowSums(RWC)`.
Then just divide RWC by the result.

```
RWC <- RWC / rowSums(RWC)
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `prop.table` with `margin` as 1.

```
prop.table(as.matrix(RWC), 1)

#          V1     V2     V3
#[1,] 0.08333 0.3333 0.5833
#[2,] 0.13333 0.3333 0.5333
#[3,] 0.16667 0.3333 0.5000
```

`prop.table` is wrapper around `sweep`

```
sweep(RWC, 1, rowSums(RWC), `/`)
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using a `for` loop, you can use `apply` function:

```r
apply(RWC,1, function(x) round(x/sum(x),2))

   [,1] [,2] [,3]
X1 0.08 0.13 0.17
X2 0.33 0.33 0.33
X3 0.58 0.53 0.50
```